# Google app scrip to move file to google drive from Gmail make blank 15byte file

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, google-drive-api, gmail

Hey any help apprechated to make this app scrip work or enhance.

Scrip make the blank PDF that is 15 bytes in the right place trying to gett he PDF to show content thanks.

```
function saveAttachmentsToDrive() {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var subFolder = getOrCreateFolder(rootFolder, "testsaveattachments");
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var attachments = messages[j].getAttachments();

      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];

        if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf") {
          var fileName = attachment.getName();
          var fileBlob = attachment.copyBlob();

          try {
            subFolder.createFile(fileName, fileBlob);
          } catch (error) {
            Logger.log("Error saving attachment: " + error);
          }
        }

        Utilities.sleep(1000); // 1-second delay before processing the next attachment.
      }
    }
  }
}

function getOrCreateFolder(parentFolder, folderName) {
  var folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);

  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    return folders.next();
  } else {
    return parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  }
}
```

Not tried all sorts but can not make it work

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing script and your issue of `Scrip make the blank PDF that is 15 bytes in the right place`, I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to `subFolder.createFile(fileName, fileBlob)`. In your script, `fileName` and `fileBlob` are the string and the blob, respectively. In the case of the method of `createFile(name, content)`, `name` and `content` are required to be both strings. In this case, it is required to be `createFile(fileBlob)`.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf") {
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var fileBlob = attachment.copyBlob();

  try {
    subFolder.createFile(fileName, fileBlob);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error saving attachment: " + error);
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
if (attachment.getContentType() === "application/pdf") {
  var fileBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
  try {
    subFolder.createFile(fileBlob);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error saving attachment: " + error);
  }
}
```

- By this modification, `fileBlob` is correctly used with the method of `createFile`. And, the file is created to `subFolder`.

#### References:

- [createFile(name, content)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content)
- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)